# Sort an array of objects according to various field

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I have an array of objects like

```
const data = [
  {
    bid: 15000,
    product: "hotel",
    bdetails: { event_start_date: "2021-04-28 00:00:00" },
  },

  {
    bid: 15001,
    product: "hotel",
    bdetails: { event_start_date: "2021-04-27 00:00:00" },
  },

  {
    bid: 15002,
    product: "flight",
    bdetails: { depart: "2019-06-18 07:55:00" },
  },

  {
    bid: 15003,
    product: "flight",
    bdetails: { depart: "2019-06-18 08:55:00" },
  },

  {
    bid: 15004,
    product: "hotel",
    bdetails: { event_start_date: "2021-04-28 00:00:00" },
  },
];
```

So i need to apply multiple sorting order here

1. All items with product="flight" will come at first
2. All items with product="hotel" will come at last
3. Among all items with "flight", they are to be sorted by "bdetails.depart" in ascending order
4. All items with "hotel" are to be sorted by "bdetails.event_start_date" in ascending order

As of now i was able to sort "flights" first and "hotels" last by the logic

```
data.sort((a, b) => {

    if (a.product == 'flight') {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return b.product == 'flight' ? 1 : 0;
    }
  });
```

But now I am messing up to sort them acc. to bdetails.depart and bdetails.event_start_date for flights and hotels respectively.

Comment: i would suggest sorting them twice in different sorts. First the dates and then the products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create 2 separate arrays for hotels and flights. Sort them based on the respective properties in that order.

```
const hotels = [],
      flights = []

for (const o of data) {
  if (o.product === 'flight')
    flights.push(o)
  else if (o.product === 'hotel')
    hotels.push(o)
}

flights.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.bdetails.depart) - new Date(b.bdetails.depart))
hotels.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.bdetails.event_start_date) - new Date(a.bdetails.event_start_date))

const output = flights.concat(hotels)
```

---

You can make it dynamic. You could create an `order` object which has

- each `product` as key.
- `priority` for each `product`
- `direction` of sort: `1` for ascending and `-1` for descending
- The inner property name from `bdetails` which needs to be used for Date sorting

If you have more `product` values, and custom Date property names, you could just add to this object.

```js
const data=[{bid:15000,product:"hotel",bdetails:{event_start_date:"2021-04-28 00:00:00"},},{bid:15001,product:"hotel",bdetails:{event_start_date:"2021-04-27 00:00:00"},},{bid:15002,product:"flight",bdetails:{depart:"2019-06-18 07:55:00"},},{bid:15003,product:"flight",bdetails:{depart:"2019-06-18 08:55:00"},},{bid:15004,product:"hotel",bdetails:{event_start_date:"2021-04-28 00:00:00"},},];

const order = {
  "flight": {
    priority: 1,
    direction: 1,
    sortProp: "depart",
  },
  "hotel": {
    priority: 2,
    direction: -1,
    sortProp: "event_start_date"
  }
}

data.sort((a, b) => {
  const productSort = order[a.product].priority - order[b.product].priority

  if (productSort)
    return productSort

  const { direction, sortProp } = order[a.product];

  return direction * (new Date(a.bdetails[sortProp]) - new Date(b.bdetails[sortProp]))
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this,
In our custom sort function, we assign a priority to both the product types and try to sort on that basis, if priority is same then we sort by `bdetails.depart` for flight and `bdetails.event_start_date` for hotels

```js
const sortData = (data) => {
    const priority = {
        flight: 1,
        hotel: 2
    };

    return data.sort((itemA, itemB) => {
        const diff = priority[itemA.product] - priority[itemB.product];
        if (diff !== 0) return diff;

        // The two items have same product
        const product = itemA.product;
        return product === 'flight' ? 
            new Date(itemA.bdetails.depart) - new Date(itemB.bdetails.depart) :
            new Date(itemB.bdetails.event_start_date) - new Date(itemA.bdetails.event_start_date);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing manual sorting is error prone especially with dates. It will be wise to delegate to lodash(https://lodash.com/)
As for your solution It is easy to do with the help of lodash as follows

```js
import _ from 'lodash'

const hotels = data.filter(x => x.product === 'hotel')
const orderedHotels = _.orderBy(hotels, ['bdetails.event_start_date'], ['asc'])
const flights = data.filter(x => x.product === 'flight')
const orderedFlights = _.orderBy(flights, ['bdetails.depart'], ['asc'])

const result = orderedFlights.concat(orderedHotels)
console.log({ hotels, orderedHotels, flights,  orderedFlights, result })
```

Result will be

```
[{
        "bid": 15001,
        "product": "hotel",
        "bdetails": {
          "event_start_date": "2021-04-27 00:00:00"
        }
      }, {
        "bid": 15000,
        "product": "hotel",
        "bdetails": {
          "event_start_date": "2021-04-28 00:00:00"
        }
      }, {
        "bid": 15004,
        "product": "hotel",
        "bdetails": {
          "event_start_date": "2021-04-28 00:00:00"
        }
      }, {
        "bid": 15002,
        "product": "flight",
        "bdetails": {
          "depart": "2019-06-18 07:55:00"
        }
      }, {
        "bid": 15003,
        "product": "flight",
        "bdetails": {
          "depart": "2019-06-18 08:55:00"
}]
```

Comment: can you suggest something more vanilla? why would you want a whole library just to sort some arrays?

Comment: I like the part about breaking down hotels and flights into 2 arrays and then contactenating them

Comment: FYI. He needs flights first

Comment: Something that works is better than perfect.